# How can I replicate putty's capabilities in gnome-terminal?

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty

I connect to my workplace via citrix. Now to connect to servers, I currently use putty. This is because in putty, I can use the proxy settings options to add connect via HTTP proxy which is set to 127.0.0.1:3218.
How can I achieve the same from a gnome terminal without affecting the whole system's configuration?

I have tried `connect-proxy -H 127.0.0.1:3218 server-name 22` . But this gives an error 
`FATAL: failed to begin relaying via HTTP.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to remote SSH Server via HTTP proxy, you need to install `connect-proxy`

Then edit your ~/.ssh/config file like this => [~/.ssh/config](https://gist.github.com/terrywang/3997931)

```
## Outside of the firewall, with HTTPS proxy
## Package connect-proxy is required.

# VPS
Host server-name
  ProxyCommand connect -H proxy.company.com:80  %h %p
  ServerAliveInterval 20

# Amazon EC2
Host *.compute.amazonaws.com
  ProxyCommand connect -H proxy.company.com:80 %h %p
  ServerAliveInterval 30

# cloud.terry.im
Host cloud.terry.im
  ProxyCommand connect -H proxy.company.com:80 %h %p
  ServerAliveInterval 30

## Inside the firewall (do not use proxy)
Host *
   ProxyCommand connect %h %p
```

Make necessary changes to adapt your environment.

Then use `ssh user@server-name` and you'll see it works.

BTW: `socat` or `corkscrew` can probably archive the same.